# How do I include the wildcard in a returned expression with gsub in R?

Tags: r, gsub

I have a string in R:

```
mystring <- "2 and 4"
```

I want to use gsub to put " hours" after every occurance of a number, so that the string looks like this:

```
"2 hours and 4 hours"
```

I have tried this, which matches the number, but I want the number returned in the output:

```
gsub("\\d{1}", "\\d{1} hours", mystring)
[1] "d{1} hours and d{1} hours"
```

How do I include the original number in the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We capture the digit (`\\d`) before the word boundary (`\\b`) as a group and in the replacement, specify the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group followed by space and then the substring 'hours'

```
gsub("(\\d)\\b", "\\1 hours", mystring)
[1] "2 hours and 4 hours"
```

Answer (score 2):

With `stringr`, we can use an R function on the match to construct the replacement:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(
  mystring,
  "\\d",
  \(x) paste(x, "hours")
)
# [1] "2 hours and 4 hours"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a non consuming look behind:

```
gsub("(?<=\\d)", " hours", mystring, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "2 hours and 4 hours"
```

In case there are more digits use a boundary in addition:

```
gsub("(?<=\\d)\\b", " hours", mystring, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "2 hours and 4 hours"
```